# UTF-16 file output in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

```
chcp 10000
echo hell☺ w☻rld♥! >> "UTF-16 file☺☻♥♦♣♠"
```

OK, it creates correct file, but in the content there are question marks instead of unicode characters. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not correct, as 10000 is not a Unicode code page. See [Code Page Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
10000   macintosh   MAC Roman; Western European (Mac)
...
1200    utf-16      Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications
1201    unicodeFFFE Unicode UTF-16, big endian byte order; available only to managed applications
...
12000   utf-32      Unicode UTF-32, little endian byte order; available only to managed applications
12001   utf-32BE    Unicode UTF-32, big endian byte order; available only to managed applications
...
65000   utf-7       Unicode (UTF-7)
65001   utf-8       Unicode (UTF-8)
```

I'm not sure why, but the Command Prompt seems to interpret them as control characters when pasted, specifically SOH (Start of Heading, 01), STX (Start of Text, 02) and ETX (End of Text, 03).

On the plus side, PowerShell seems to handle this properly. Notepad++ opened the resultant text file as "UCS-2 Little Endian" automatically, and it displays the correct characters.

---

Ok, I've figured out why UTF-8 wasn't working for me. The font should be set to Lucida Console, since the default Raster Fonts don't have Unicode support.

Comment: chcp 1200 : console says: "Invalid code page", as well ass with chcp 1201. Why?

Comment: @kutacz **`available only to managed applications`**. Use PowerShell for proper Unicode support, since the UTF-8 option (`65001`) doesn't seem to work in the Command Prompt for this case.

Comment: In case of UTF-8(after chcp 65001) it works fine...

Comment: @kutacz Well, then, use UTF-8. It didn't seem to work for me, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. UTF-16 is not possible in the standard Command Prompt. Managed applications probably refers to the .NET Framework. PowerShell runs on the .NET Framework, so it works for UTF-16.

Comment: [Fixed dead link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)

Answer (score 2):

Both `65001.txt` and `1200.txt` contain the same string:`абв™` but in different encoding. The command:

```
chcp 65001 & type 65001.txt
```

successfully changes the codepage, but displays the garbage.

The command:

```
type 1200.txt
```

displays the correct characters, but the command

```
for /f %A in ('type 1200.txt') do echo %A
```

displays `абвT`.

So cmd.exe IS able to work with codepage 1200 (with some limits) while I can't get any satisfactory results with codepage 65001.